# When does connected space imply locally connectness?

Tags: general-topology

Okay, I'm a little bit new with with connected spaces etc.
And I understand now that a connected space doesn't have to be locally connected.
But it seems like this is almost always true, (as the counter example they give is quite hairy). Now I'm wondering is it not possible to say that for this and that cases it is true that a connected space $X$ is always also locally connected ?

Comment: Being connected is very different from being locally connected. I think, this is very broad question.

Comment: "almost all" topological spaces are so strange that we cannot imagine them... Maybe you are thinking that almost all spaces you know are manifolds, and certainly they are locally connected.

Comment: @GEdgar A professor of mine was wont to say that one needs heavy drugs in order to imagine the most of them...

Comment: GEdgar is, of course, perfectly correct. However, even the image of a manifold under an injective local embedding need not be locally connected. For example, a line of irrational slope in the unit square torus is path connected, but not locally connected (to the same extent that $\mathbf{Q}$ is not locally connected). Moreover, these examples are arguably "natural". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "quite hairy" is examples of spaces that are not locally connected, whether they be connected or not. The property of being locally connected really has nothing to do with being globally connected. Here's a thought in order to convince you: X is locally connected iff $X \sqcup \{*\}$ is locally connected (so it doesn't help that $X$ is connected for it to be locally connected).